# ItemReader reader() in infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I implemented ItemReader  with JdbcTemplate .

The problem is that `read()` is being invoked in infinite loop.

```
public class MyReader implements ItemReader<Col>, InitializingBean {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private RowMapper<Col> rowMapper;
    private String sql;
    private DataSource dataSource;

public Col read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
     Col col = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,null, rowMapper);            
     return col;
    }

}
```

Spring batch configuration:

```
<chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1" />


<bean id="itemReader"
    class="batch.MyReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="#{stepExecutionContext[sql]}" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="batch.ColMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: And why shouldn't it? It will be invoked as long as the `read` method returns something, it will end when the method returns `null`. Also why aren't you just using one of the default `ItemReader`? Looks like you can simply use one of the defaults instead of implementing your own...

Comment: I was using JdbcCursorItemReader  before but in my case I need to return only the first row. (One field)

Answer (score 5):

That's the way a Spring Batch step works: the ItemReader.read() method will be called until it returns null.

Comment: What can I do then?
I am not using using JdbcCursorItemReader  because I need to return only the first row. (One field)

Comment: Using a ItemReader to read just one line seems overkill... but anyway the simplest solution is having a flag to return null when the read method is called more than once

Comment: I am using ItemReader becasue, I need retrieve multiple values from multiple sqls. So I am using partitioner execution via SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor