# Spring Batch read step running in loop

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-batch

I came across a piece of code that reads some data as the following:

```
public class StudioReader implements ItemReader<List<Studio>> {
   @Setter private AreaDao areaDao;
   @Getter @Setter private BatchContext context;
   private HopsService hopsService = new HopsService();

   @Override
   public List<Studio> read() throws Exception {
      List<Studio> list = hopsService.getStudioHops();
      if (!isEmpty(list)) {
         for (Studio studio : list) {
            log.info("Studio being read: {}", studio.getCode());
            List areaList = areaDao.getArea(studio
                  .getCode());
            if (areaList.size() > 0) {
               studio.setArea((String) areaList.get(0));
               log.info("Area {1} is fetched for studio {2}", areaList.get(0), studio.getCode());
            }
            this.getContext().setReadCount(1);
         }
      }
      return list;
   }
```

However when I run the job this read is running in a loop. I found from another stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069624/itemreader-reader-in-infinite-loop) that it is the expected behavior. My question then is what is the best solution given this particular example? Extend StudioReader from JdbcCursorItemReader ? I found one example that defines everything in the xml which I don't want. And here is the context.xml part for the reader:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
   <bean id="ItemReader" class="com.syc.studio.reader.StudioReader" scope="step">
      <property name="context" ref="BatchContext" />
      <property name="areaDao" ref="AreaDao" />
   </bean>
```

And here is the job definition in xml:

```
 <bean id="StudioJob" class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob">
      <property name="steps">
         <list>
                     <bean id="StudioStep" parent="SimpleStep" >
                     <property name="itemReader" ref="ItemReader"/>
                     <property name="itemWriter" ref="ItemWriter"/>
                     <property name="retryableExceptionClasses">
                        <map>
                           <entry key="com.syc.studio.exception.CustomException" value="true"/>
                        </map>
                     </property>
                     <property name="retryLimit" value="2" />
                     </bean>
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
   </bean>
```

Writer:

```
public void write(List<? extends Object> obj) throws Exception {
   List<Studio> list = (List<Studio>) obj.get(0);
   for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
      Studio studio = list.get(i);
      if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new APIClient("v2");
     }
      this.uploadXML(studio);
   }
```

The read method after suggestion from @holi-java:

```
public List<Studio> read() throws Exception {
    if (this.listIterator == null) {
        this.listIterator = initializing();
    }
    return this.listIterator.hasNext() ? this.listIterator.next() : null;
}

private Iterator<List<Studio>> initializing() {
    List<Studio> listOfStudiosFromApi = hopsService.getStudioLocations();
    for (Studio studio : listOfStudiosFromApi) {
        log.info("Studio being read: {}", studio.getCode());
        List areaList = areaDao.getArea(studio.getCode());
        if (areaList.size() > 0) {
            studio.setArea((String) areaList.get(0));
            log.info("Area {1} is fetched for studio {2}", areaList.get(0), studio.getCode());
        }
        this.getContext().setReadCount(1);
    }
    return Collections.singletonList(listOfStudiosFromApi).iterator();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ItemReader reader() in infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069624/itemreader-reader-in-infinite-loop)

Comment: @MichaelMinella He literally linked to that post, not to mention that post doesn't even have a solution...

Comment: @Yana  `foreach` loop in `initializing` method should be using an `ItemProcessor` . it's not a responsibility of `ItemReader`  and `ItemReader` violate [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spring-batch documentation for [ItemReader.read](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html#read--) assert:

> Implementations must return **null** at the end of the input data set.

But your read method is always return a List and should be like this:

```
public Studio read() throws Exception {
    if (this.results == null) {
        List<Studio> list = hopsService.getStudioHops();
        ...
        this.results=list.iterator();
    }
    return this.results.hasNext() ? this.results.next() : null;
}
```

if you want your read method return a List then you must paging the results like this:

```
public List<Studio> read() throws Exception {
    List<Studio> results=hopsService.getStudioHops(this.page++);
    ...
    return results.isEmpty()?null:results;
}
```

if you can't paging the results from Service you can solved like this:

```
public List<Studio> read() throws Exception {
    if(this.results==null){
     this.results = Collections.singletonList(hopsService.getStudioHops()).iterator();
    }

    return this.results.hasNext()?this.results.next():null;
}
```

it's better not read a list of items `List<Studio>`, read an item at a time `Studio` instead. when you read a list of item you possibly duplicated iterate logic between `writers` and `processors` as you have shown the demo in comments. if you have a huge of data list to processing you can combine pagination in your reader, for example:

```
public Studio read() throws Exception {
    if (this.results == null || !this.results.hasNext()) {
        List<Studio> list = hopsService.getStudioHops(this.page++);
        ...
        this.results=list.iterator();
    }

    return this.results.hasNext() ? this.results.next() : null;
}
```

Maybe you need to see [step processing mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing).

- [ItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html) - read an item at a time.
- [ItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemProcessor.html) - processing an item at a time.
- [ItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html)  - write [entire chunk of items](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html#write-java.util.List-) out.

Comment: thanks - but a little confused as your example doesn't return a list - can you please clarify?

Comment: @Yana an reader is read an item at a time not a list of item.if you read a list of items,then your writer maybe like this: `write(List<List<Studio>>)`.

Comment: @Yana if you read a list of items at a time.you must paging the results in `reader.read`.

Comment: @Yana better not to read a list of items at a time,it will resulting in duplications in `reader`, `writer` and `processor`.

Comment: read() method is what I've here - also I see this [example](https://github.com/valcom/Uscite-Batch/blob/586a73acdcc2da254a1959e62ca0259bec6bb276/Uscite-Batch/src/main/java/it/ccse/uscite/batch/usernameBatch/StoricoReader.java) - however I am not sure exactly what will go inside it

Comment: not sure what that is doing! that service call doesn't take any param (and returns a list of hops) ... we cannot change that... but I see your goal is "exhausting" the list - correct?

Comment: @Yana see section "can't paging from Service"

Comment: thanks @holi-java I've added the complete read method after your suggestion - let me know if that's what you suggested (and yes I realized why one Studio should be read, there is bad duplication, but the problem is I can't change the service)

Comment: @Yana it's not I suggested that is spring-batch suggested. your reader can work correctly now?

Comment: its your "can't paging the results from Service" solution is what I followed - have a look at my edit - does that look good? or do I need to change something else?

Comment: @Yana it's can run correctly now? I need the result because I never test with it.